# fetching data from external JSON file into an innerHTML table using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, innerhtml

I have created an HTML table called players_table consisting of 3 variables(**ID, Name, Country**)
The table should display the fetched JSON data into its rows. I don't know what's wrong and why it isn't fetching anything. Could you please help me out fix this error and display results into the table?

---

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $.getJSON("GameDb.json", function(data)
            {
                var player_data = '';
                $.each(data,function(key,value)
                {
                    player_data +='<tr>';
                    player_data +='<td>'+value.Id+'</td>';
                    player_data +='<td>'+value.Name+'</td>';
                    player_data +='<td>'+value.Country+'</td>';
                    player_data +='</tr>';
                });

                    $('#players_table').append(player_data);
        });

    });

    </script>
```

---

The console is not showing any errors. However, the entire table cells are showing the word "Undefined".
This is the view from my end.

[image: The Screen view]

Comment: do you have errors in `dev tool` console? if you have error add it to your question

Comment: No sir, there are no errors shown in the console. However, the entire table cells are displaying the word "Undefined".

Comment: add `console.log(data);` right before `var player_data = '';` and see what you get in the console, maybe `data` is not an array.

Comment: The Console showed [Sending APH request.....................antiphishing.js:1]